# extract data from JSON to datagridview winforms c#

Tags: c#, datagridview, json.net

I'm trying to extract data from **JSON** but i searched and tried many examples but nothing worked for me. I just want messages node and extract its data to **datagridview**. Json Object looks like:

```
{
"limit" : "10",
"offset" : "0",
"size" : "10",
"messages": [{
 "address": "+12111",
"body": "hello",
"_id": "4113",
"msg_box": "inbox",
"sim_slot": "0"
},
{
"address": "78454",
"body": "my data",
"_id": "4103",
"msg_box": "inbox",
"sim_slot": "0"
},
{
"address": "7421",
"body": "yes",
"_id": "4101",
"msg_box": "outbox",
"sim_slot": "0"
},
{
"address": "+1235454878",
"body": "balance",
"_id": "4099",
"msg_box": "inbox",
"sim_slot": "0"
},
{
"address": "+123545",
"body": "hello",
"_id": "4098",
"msg_box": "inbox",
"sim_slot": "0"
}
]
}
```

Comment: Welcome.  Can you show us your code.  This will help us help you.  Good luck! [ask]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have JSON but don't know how to create corresponding classes that deserialize the JSON into objects, [json2csharp.com](http://json2csharp.com/) is helpful. You paste in the JSON and it does its best to infer C# classes from it. You might decide to tweak the classes a little as needed but it gives you a good starting point. Given your JSON it outputs this:

```
public class Message
{
    public string address { get; set; }
    public string body { get; set; }
    public string _id { get; set; }
    public string msg_box { get; set; }
    public string sim_slot { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public string limit { get; set; }
    public string offset { get; set; }
    public string size { get; set; }
    public List<Message> messages { get; set; }
}
```

Now using [Newtonsoft.Json](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/) you can do this:

```
var myObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(stringContainingJson);
```

A property named `_id` is a little clunky, so you can change the name and use an attribute to map the the property to the JSON element, like this:

```
[JsonProperty("_id")]
public string Id { get; set; }
```

Now you can bind the list of `Message` to your `DataGridView`.

```
myDataGridView.DataSource = myObject.messages;
```

Comment: your code helped me too much. thanks for sharing your knowledge.